# How to insert an element after every other element in a sublist?

Tags: python, list, python-3.8

I have this list:

`sep = [['IN', 'the', 'midway', 'of', 'this', 'our', 'mortal', 'life'], ['I', 'found', 'me', 'in', 'a', 'gloomy', 'wood', 'astray'], ['Gone', 'from', 'the', 'path', 'direct', 'and', 'e','en', 'to', 'tell'], ['It', 'were', 'no', 'easy', 'task', 'how', 'savage', 'wild'], ['That','forest', 'how', 'robust', 'and', 'rough', 'its', 'growth'], ['Which', 'to', 'remember', 'only', 'my', 'dismay'], ['Renews', 'in', 'bitterness', 'not', 'far', 'from', 'death']]`

How can I put a "0" in every sub-element?

The final result is supposed to be:

`[['IN', '0', 'the', '0', 'midway', '0', 'of', '0', 'this', '0', 'our', '0', 'mortal', '0', 'life', '0' ], ['I', '0', 'found', '0', 'me', '0', 'in', '0', 'a', '0', 'gloomy', '0', 'wood', '0', 'astray', '0'], ['Gone', '0', 'from', '0', 'the', '0', 'path', '0', 'direct', '0', 'and', '0', 'e', '0', 'en', '0', 'to', '0', 'tell', '0'], ['It', '0', 'were', '0', 'no', '0', 'easy', '0', 'task', '0', 'how', '0', 'savage', '0', 'wild', '0'], ['That', '0', 'forest', '0', 'how', '0', 'robust', '0', 'and', '0', 'rough', '0', 'its', '0', 'growth', '0'], ['Which', '0', 'to', '0', 'remember', '0', 'only', '0', 'my', '0', 'dismay', '0'], ['Renews', '0', 'in', '0', 'bitterness', '0', 'not', '0', 'far', '0', 'from', '0', 'death','0']]`

Comment: `sep = [[v for t in zip(l, cycle('0')) for v in t] for l in sep]` something like this? cycle is itertools.cycle

Comment: I need a solution without using external libraries

Comment: @Dino,  Why do you need a solution without using external libraries ? if it is an exercice, at least, what did you tried?

Comment: Ch3steR's solution is very clever and can easily be adapted to work without itertools. just replace `cycle('0')` with `['0']*len(l)`...

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer:

```py
def sep_list(s,c,n=2):
  def gen(s,c,n):
    if n<2 :
      raise Exception("Number needs to be bigger than 1.")
    for x in range(0,(len(s)*n)):
      if isinstance(s[int(x/n)],list):
        yield [y for y in gen(s[int(x/n)],c,n)]
      elif x%n==0:
        yield c
      else:
        yield s[int(x/n)]
  return([x for x in gen(s,c,n)])
a=sep_list(sep,0) #list,character,distance(optional)
```

So, this function will work no matter how many sublists there are, and you can customize the gap distance. This works by taking a list and finding its length. Then it goes through the list, and if the list has another list inside, that list too. Finally, when it reaches a non-list, it counts whether it is at a set distance, and finally returns the whole list with the character at set intervals.